limit of two sequences tending to zero
Suppose there are two real-valued sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ both tending to 0 as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Are there any examples such sequences for which
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x_n}{y_n}\rightarrow 1
\end{equation*}
except the case where $x_n=y_n$ for all $n$?
I could not possibly think of anything so far.

Try $\frac1n$ and $\frac1{n+1}$.

Thank you so much!

Or $y_n = x_{n+1}$, or $y_n = x_{n+n_0}$ for any fixed $n_0$. Or $y_n = a_n x_n$ for any sequence $a_n$ that tends to $1$.

Let $\{y_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers. If $\{y_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is convergent and its limit is $0$, then the sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ defined as follows:
\begin{equation*}
x_{n} = \sin(y_{n})\hspace{0.25 cm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{equation*}
is a convergent sequence of real numbers whose limit is also $0$, given that $\sin$ is a continuous function, and that
\begin{equation*}
\sin(0) = 0\text{.}
\end{equation*}
The sequences $\{x_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ and $\{y_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ are such that
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{x_{n}}{y_{n}} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 1\text{,}
\end{equation*}
since
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \xrightarrow[x \to 0]{} 1\text{.}
\end{equation*}
Many indeterminate forms $\tfrac{0}{0}$ could yield examples of sequences with the property that you are looking for.

amazing example, thanks
